# Laravel 5: The requested URL was not found on this server

Tags: php, apache, laravel, laravel-5, debian

I have installed Laravel 5.2 through Composer in this directory `var/www/html/boh/boh`.

Even though I heard it is not recommended, I used the `chmod 777`  on the folder to have 100% access to it.

I can see the laravel welcome page properly but after trying to create user login/register forms using `php artisan make:auth` neither of the links login/register isnt working. I tried to add any route with `View::make` myself but every other link than `localhost/` is giving me this error `The requested URL was not found on this server.`

I am just a beginner in linux and I am configurating a framework for the first time. I have read all the similar topics but nothing seems to help me.

**apache.config**:

```
<Directory />
    #Options FollowSymLinks
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
    AllowOverride none
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /usr/share>
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /var/www/html/boh/boh/public>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>

#<Directory /srv/>
#   Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
#   AllowOverride None
#   Require all granted
#</Directory>
```

**Sites-available/000-default.conf** :

`DocumentRoot /var/www/html/boh/boh/public/`

**Htaccess file**:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
</IfModule>
```

I was using `sudo service apache2 restart` after every single change.
Any help please?

Comment: Had routes with `View::make`? I don't get this one. You write routes with `Route::get('foo', function () {});`

Comment: Well, I was setting some routes that were only returning a view make. To check if any links are actually working

Comment: What URLs have you tried? `http://localhost/` will point initially to `/var/www`, so your URLs should be something like `http://localhost/boh/boh/public/`.

Comment: @Jonathon I have tried `http://localhost/boh/boh/public/login` and `http://localhost/login` but none of them is working. No idea what is happening with this

Answer (score -1):

I suggest to use Homestead instead of lamp. Homestead is appropriate to laravel to run successfully your laravel application in your local machine without issues.

Homestead instructions :

1) Install VirtualBox 5.x or VMWare

2) Install Vagrant

3) Add laravel/homestead to your vagrant box with this command

4) Run this commands from your terminal :

> $ vagrant box add laravel/homestead
>
> $ cd ~
>
> $ git clone https://github.com/laravel/homestead.git
>
> $ cd Homestead
>
> $ bash init.sh

5) copy your project to ~/Code

6) configure nginx sites :
- Install vim if not installed and run :

> $ sudo vim ~/Homestead/Homestead.yaml

sites:
      map: your.app

```
  to: /home/vagrant/Code/YourProjectName/public
```

- Configure your hosts :

  > $ sudo vim ~/etc/hosts

> add 192.168.10.10  your.app to your hosts

- To update nginx changes

  > $ sudo vagrant reload --provision

Otherwise , If you want to run laravel commands you should ssh to your vagrant box using this command from your Homestead directory

> $ cd Homestead
>
> $ vagrant ssh
>
> $ cd Code/YourProjectName

then you can run all your php artisan and composer commands from here .

For more informations : https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/homestead

You can also use LaraDock which also gives you a complete virtual development environments same as homestead , just it is using containers instead of a full virtual machine ."Running a virtual Container is much faster than running a full virtual Machine" as it is said in their documentation .

For more informations please review the laradock documentation in github .